Reverse 'clamp' an Image using VW
A client would like their (SVG) logo at 8vw at viewports of 1280px and above, 'reducing' to 22vw down to viewports of 400px and below. Like a reverse clamp in some ways. Is this possible using a clamp / calc function (instead of @media) and if so, what would be the calculation please? Thank you.
I tried using clamp calculators but none that I found are dedicated to vw. Instead, the focus is on REM.
